# Restrict direct access to folder, but allow access via iframe

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net, iframe

Our customer would like to add new feature to an existing Razor MVC based webapp.
The feature has following two requirements:

1. One requirement is to render a set of html pages on /Help page view of our web-app.
   The html pages css should be independent from the web-app and should not be affected by web-app css.
   Therefor I chose to embed them into an iframe, so their css is not affected by parent webapp.
2. Another requirement is to allow only access for logged in user to these help files, and also deny any direct requests such as `http://localhost/myHtmlFiles/index.html`.

I've read suggestions to add `<authorization>` tag
 into root web.config file, but this is not an option since `<authentication/>` mode has to be set to `"None"` and authorization via web.config does work only with `"Forms"` authentication.

I'm running out of ideas how this could be implemented while ensuring both requirements are met.

Comment: You can rely on the `Referrer` header to determine whether it's a direct (parent) request or from an `IFrame`. But keep in mind that it has nothing to do with security / authorization whatsoever.

Comment: Thanks, you've pointed me to the right direction. I've added a rule to web.config file, where I allowed request with specific referrers. First referrer is the view which has the iframe embedded in it, second one is the iframe contents referrer.This way the html pages are accessible only via /Help page.